# Solve the equation in the field

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, diophantine-equations, finite-fields

How to solve the $1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6=0$ equation in the $F_{29}$?

I've found that $(a+b)^{p}=a^{p}+b^{p}$ - perhaps it might help.

Comment: "*I've found that $(a+b)^p=a^p+b^p$ (however, i didn't understand why is it so)*":  Remember your binomial theorem that $(a+b)^p=\sum\limits_{k=0}^p \binom{p}{k}a^kb^{p-k}$ and notice that for every $k\in\{1,2,\dots,p-1\}$ one has $\binom{p}{k}=\frac{p!}{k!(p-k)!}$ has a factor of $p$ in the numerator but no factor of $p$ in the denominator and is thus divisible by $p$, hence when considered as an element of of $\Bbb F_p$ instead of as $\Bbb Z$ clears out.  See further: [freshman's dream on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freshman%27s_dream).

Comment: Hints: A) Remember that the multiplicative group of $\Bbb{F}_{29}$ is cyclic of order $28=4\cdot7$. B) $1+x+\cdots+x^6=(1-x^7)/(1-x)$, so a solution of that sextic is of order $7$ (and $\neq1$).

Comment: @JMoravitz, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if your methods will work. By the way, the formula for $a^p+b^p$ works because the coefficients are the multiples of $p=29$. Try to write some out and you will see.

#### My method

First multiply your polynomial by $(x-1)$ to get $x^7-1$. Then try to solve the latter. Since we add a factor $(x-1)$, all we have to do is to collect the solutions to the latter, and get rid of $1$ (you may check $1$ is not a solution).

The **main trick** is to notice that $F_{29}^* := F_{29} -\{0\}$ is a group (of order $28$) under multiplication! So every nonzero element $a$ must satisfy $a^{28}=1$. However, $28 = 4\cdot7$, so you can easily produce lots of roots by looking at the fourth powers of the nontrivial elements.

Comment: Thanks - it's clear!

Answer (score 3):

$(x-1)(x^6+\cdots+x+1)=x^7-1$, so the roots of your polynomial are
the non-trivial seventh roots of unity. As $29-1=7\times 4$, the seventh
roots of unity in $GF(29)$ are the fourth powers of the nonzero elements, and it's easy to find those.